# google map api v3, infowindow editable~

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a google map infowindow.
the infowindow should be editable when some event is fired.

there is a question and answer about google map infowindow editable,

[How do I make the info window editable in the Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441546/how-do-i-make-the-info-window-editable-in-the-google-maps-api)

but, this is about version 2.

any idea how to infowindow editable?

refrence~
this is my addMarket function

```
 this.addMarker = function(location) {
        var iconImg = 'signpost.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location, 
          map: this.mMap,
          icon: iconImg,
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { 
            maxWidth: '50px',
            content: "some text"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(this.mMap, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(this.mMap, marker);
        this.mMarkerArray.push(marker);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can pass any HTML into the `InfoWindow`'s `content` property. So the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441546/how-do-i-make-the-info-window-editable-in-the-google-maps-api) for Google Maps v2 that you mentioned, also applies here:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
        maxWidth: '50px',
        content: '<div contentEditable="true">changeme...</div>'
    });
```